# Why formal power series are not considered a system of hypercomplex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, formal-power-series, hypercomplex-numbers

One can introduce a constant $\chi$ following all numerical properties and two additional operations $\delta$ and $\circ$, like the following:

$\delta a=0$ if a is a standard number

$\delta \chi=1$

$\delta (xz)=z\delta x+x\delta z$

If

$x=a+a_1\chi+a_2\chi^2+a_3\chi^3+...$

and

$z=b+b_1\chi+b_2\chi^2+b_3\chi^3+...$

Then 
$x\circ z=a+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+...$

so that $\chi\circ z=z$ and $z\circ\chi=z$ for any $z$

This system seems to me to possess all usual properties of real/complex numbers, and form a field. Yet it is often claimed that the usual complex numbers are the only system of (hyper-)complex numbers that forms a field. Why?

Also the proposed system will make operators and functionals just ordinary numerical functions.

Comment: Can you check the definition of $\circ$? We have that $\chi=0+1\chi+0\chi^2+...$ and then you defined $\chi\circ z=\chi$ but you claim that $\chi\circ z=z$. Also, what operation are you considering as the operations of the algebra? $+$ and $\times$ and multiplication by numbers? What is the role of $\delta$ and $\circ$? Moreover, take into account that hypercomplex are finite-dimensional by definition.

Comment: What exactly do mean by «a system of (hyper-)complex numbers»?

Comment: My guess is, I am not the only one who has no idea whatsoever about what you mean by «operators and functionals.»

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does not form a field is quite simply the lack of multiplicative inverses. (it is clearly a ring, namely $\mathbb{C}[\chi]$).

Under standard multiplication $\chi$ has no inverse as $k\chi \notin \mathbb{C}$ if $k\in \mathbb{C}$ and $\chi *\chi = \chi^2$.

So assuming you wish to use composition of functions as your multiplication, we have $2+\chi$ having no inverse:

Suppose $\alpha = (2+\chi)^{-1}$ then $1 = (2+\chi) \circ \alpha = 2+ \alpha $ from the definition of $\circ$ hence $\alpha = -1$ but $\alpha \circ (2+\chi) = -1 \circ (2+\chi) = -1$ which is not the identity.

Comment: LOL who said you composition of functions should be multiplication? What hypercomplex system is built this way?

Comment: @Anixx: Hypercomplex numbers are elements of a finite-dimensional algebra with a unit element over the field of real numbers. Do you use the term *hypercomplex system* as synonym for hypercomplex number? Could you also address the aspect of *finite* dimension in your question?

Comment: @Anixx, your question talks about a derivation and composition, neither of which has anything to do with usual notions of hypercomplex numbers. Since you have chosen *not* tp expand on what excatly you mean by that, not what Composition and derivatives have to do with anything, one can but guess.

Comment: @Anixx: That "LOL" in your comment on the answer of someone who's trying to help you is something indicating I'll better stay away from your questions in the future to avoid to gather such bad loughter myself...